# How to Mock non-default import using Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

How can I mock a function that is being imported inside the file that contains the function I am testing?

without putting it in the **mocks** folder.

```js
// FileIWantToTest.js
import { externalFunction } from '../../differentFolder';

export const methodIwantToTest = (x) => { externalFunction(x + 1) }
```

I need to make sure that `externalFunction` is called and its called with the correct arguments.

Seems super simple but the documentation doesn't cover how to do this without mocking the module for all the files in the test by putting the mocks in the **mocks** folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution: I need to take my jest.mock call outside of any test or any other function because jest needs to hoist it. Also for named exports like in my case I also have to use the following syntax:

```
jest.mock('../../differentFolder', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  externalFunction: jest.fn(),
 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest approaches is to import the library and use [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to spy on the method:

```
import { methodIwantToTest } from './FileIWantToTest';
import * as lib from '../../differentFolder';  // import the library containing externalFunction

test('methodIwantToTest', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'externalFunction');  // spy on externalFunction
  methodIwantToTest(1);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: As your linked documentation points out, by default a spy calls the original implementation, probably the last thing someone wants to do in a test, so you need to also provide a mock implementation `jest.spyOn(lib, 'externalFunction).mockImplementation(() => {})`

Comment: @Novaterata "mock" and "spy" are sometimes used interchangeably, like in the `Jest` documentation where it says ["Mock functions are also known as "spies"..."](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api).  The OP said "I need to make sure that `externalFunction` is called and its called with the correct arguments".  For that, creating a `spy` with `jest.spyOn` is all that is needed.  Replacing the implementation was not listed as a requirement, but you are right that it can be done by calling `mockImplementation`.